# Domain and Range of a modulus functional

Tags: functions

How to find range of $\frac{x}{1+|x|}$ ?
I can easily find the domain of this function. But don't know how to proceed for range.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Notice that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $$ x \lt 1 + |x|$$

So the denominator will always be larger than the numerator. The magnitude of the denominator will always be larger than the magnitude of numerator by $1$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$x = \begin{cases}|x| & x\geq 0 \\ -|x| & x < 0\end{cases}$

So, you need only consider the two cases

$\pm \frac{|x|}{1+|x|}=\pm\frac{1+|x|-1}{1+|x|}= \pm \left( 1-\frac{1}{1+|x|}\right)$

From $1+|x| \geq 1$ you can quickly derive
$$0 \leq 1-\frac{1}{1+|x|}<1 \Leftrightarrow -1 < - \left( 1-\frac{1}{1+|x|}\right) \leq 0$$
So, you get 
$$\boxed{-1 < \frac{x}{1+|x|}< 1} $$

Answer (score 1):

Given: $y=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$, the domain:
$$1+|x|\ne 0 \iff |x|\ne -1 \Rightarrow  x\in \mathbb R.$$
the range:
$$\begin{cases}\begin{align}x&=0 \Rightarrow \frac{0}{1+0}=0;\\
x&>0 \Rightarrow 0<\frac{x}{1+x}<\color{blue}{1} \iff 0<x<x+1;\\
x&<0 \Rightarrow \color{red}{-1}<\frac x{1-x}<0 \iff -1+x<x<0.\end{align}\end{cases} \Rightarrow -1<\frac{x}{1+|x|}<1.$$
Note that $y=\color{blue}{1}$ and $y=\color{red}{-1}$ are the horizontal assymptotes of the hyperbolic functions.